# how can i access the kwargs directly inside a class?

Tags: python, keyword-argument

```
class Scar:
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.make=kwargs.get("make")
        self.model=kwargs.get("model")
        self.manufacturing_year=kwargs.get("manufacturing_year")
    def print_details(self):
        print(self.make)
        print(self.model)
        print(self.manufacturing_year)
my_first_car=Scar(make="mahindra")
my_first_car.print_details()
```

why i cant print(kwargs) in print_details as it is a dictionary

Comment: Because `kwargs` is a local variable inside `__init__`, and is discarded when that function is done. You're not saving `kwargs` to an attribute, like you do with `make` etc, so the value simply doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```py
class Scar:
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.make=kwargs.get("make")
        self.model=kwargs.get("model")
        self.manufacturing_year=kwargs.get("manufacturing_year")
        self.init_kwargs = kwargs
        #    ^^^^^^^^^^^ or any name you prefer
    def print_details(self):
        print(self.make)
        print(self.model)
        print(self.manufacturing_year)
        print(self.init_kwargs)  # <--- added this print
my_first_car=Scar(make="mahindra", stack_overflow=True)
my_first_car.print_details()
```

```
mahindra
None
None
{'make': 'mahindra', 'stack_overflow': True}
```